# Svelte Mount DOM Element from Javascript

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to mount a `pixi.js` canvas with Svelte like below. `app.view` is an `HTML Canvas` element but I'm not sure how to display it with Svelte.

```
<script>
    import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let app = new PIXI.Application({ 
        width: 256,         // default: 800
        height: 256,        // default: 600
        antialias: true,    // default: false
        transparent: false, // default: false
        resolution: 1       // default: 1
    })
</script>

<style></style>

<app.view />
```

I'm just using this for the time being but it would be great to be able to add it to the template.

```
    onMount(() => {
        document.body.appendChild(app.view);
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs of [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element)

> To get a reference to a DOM node, use `bind:this`.

```html
<div bind:this={container}/>
```

```js
let container;
onMount(() => {
  container.appendChild(app.view);
});
```

Here's a live example: https://svelte.dev/repl/118b7d4540c64f8491d10a24e68948d7?version=3.12.1

If you want to avoid the wrapper element or instantiate the canvas yourself, you could create the Pixi app in `onMount` and pass it a canvas element:

```html
<canvas bind:this={view}/>
```

```js
let view;
let app;
onMount(() => {
  app = new PIXI.Application({
    view,
    // ...other props
  });
});
```

See also [the official `bind:this` example](https://svelte.dev/examples#bind-this) that uses a canvas.

Comment: Thanks @ryanatkn, this is super useful!