# How do I import pixi.js into a Svelte/Sapper app?

Tags: svelte, pixi.js, rollupjs, sapper

I'm new to Svelte and am trying to import pixi.js into my app. I've tried to import pixi.js into my svelte app following this post [Svelte Mount DOM Element from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014699/svelte-mount-dom-element-from-javascript)

I've installed pixi via:

```
yarn add pixi.js --dev
```

However, when I try to import pixi.js I get a "ReferenceError: window is not defined" error. Here is a quick example:

```
<script>
    import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let view;
    let app;
    onMount(() => {
        app = new PIXI.Application({
        view,
        // ...other props
    });
});

</script>
<canvas bind:this={view}/>
```

I read somewhere on reddit that I need to solve this using:

```
  onMount(async ()=>{       
       const PIXI = await import('pixi.js');
        app = new PIXI.Application({
        view,
        // ...other props
        });
    });
```

But that didn't work either. All is well when I use a global script tag, but I would rather use the import above. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit:
After some research I have learned that I need to approach this from a non-SSR perspective. https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Making_a_component_SSR_compatible

Here's what I tried:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let MyComponent;
  onMount(async () => {
    const module = await import ('../components/pixi/mycomponent.svelte');
    MyComponent = module.default;
   });
</script>

<svelte:component this={MyComponent}/>
```

mycomponent.svelte:

```
<script>
   import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
   import { onMount } from 'svelte';

   let view;
   let app;
     app = new PIXI.Application({
       view,
        width: 256,         // default: 800
         height: 256,        // default: 600
         antialias: true,    // default: false
         transparent: false, // default: false
         resolution: 1,      // default: 1
         backgroundColor: 0x090f15
       // ...other props
     });
</script>

<style>
 canvas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>

<div class="content" bp="padding">
  <canvas bind:this={view} />
</div>
```

Now I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "url". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Apparently pixi.js cannot be found? Is there something wrong with my rollup.config.js?

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import config from 'sapper/config/rollup.js';
import pkg from './package.json';

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const dev = mode === 'development';
const legacy = !!process.env.SAPPER_LEGACY_BUILD;

const onwarn = (warning, onwarn) => (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY' && /[/\\]@sapper[/\\]/.test(warning.message)) || onwarn(warning);
const dedupe = importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/');
const postcssOptions = () => ({
  extensions: ['.scss', '.sass'],
  extract: false,
  minimize: true,
  use: [
    ['sass', {
      includePaths: [
        './src/theme',
        './node_modules',
        // This is only needed because we're using a local module. :-/
        // Normally, you would not need this line.
        //path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')
      ]
    }]
  ]
});

export default {
  client: {
    input: config.client.input(),
    output: config.client.output(),
    plugins: [
      replace({
        'process.browser': true,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
      }),
      svelte({
        dev,
        hydratable: true,
        emitCss: false,
        css: true
      }),
      resolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe
      }),
      commonjs(),

      postcss(postcssOptions()),

      legacy && babel({
        extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte'],
        runtimeHelpers: true,
        exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**'],
        presets: [
          ['@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: '> 0.25%, not dead'
          }]
        ],
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
          ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
            useESModules: true
          }]
        ]
      }),

      !dev && terser({
        module: true
      })
    ],

    onwarn,
  },

  server: {
    input: config.server.input(),
    output: config.server.output(),
    plugins: [
      replace({
        'process.browser': false,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
      }),
      svelte({
        generate: 'ssr',
        dev
      }),
      resolve({
        dedupe
      }),
      commonjs(),

      postcss(postcssOptions())
    ],
    external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(
      require('module').builtinModules || Object.keys(process.binding('natives'))
    ),

    onwarn,
  },

  serviceworker: {
    input: config.serviceworker.input(),
    output: config.serviceworker.output(),
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      replace({
        'process.browser': true,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
      }),
      commonjs(),
      !dev && terser()
    ],

    onwarn,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently I needed to:

```
preferBuiltins: false,
```

In my client resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue above, but the provided answer did not solve my problem *entirely*.

**The whole problem (for me):**

My problem was two-fold. The heart of the issues does come down to SSR.

First, I had to set `preferBuiltins: false` and tweak the commonjs resource loader, similar to the answer given above.

Second, I was running `polka@version:next` (polka is Sapper's default microserver), which apparently was not stable/compatible in some regard. I don't know the exact incompatibility, but this intuitive fix solved my problem in the end. I simply changed my `package.json` and ran `npm install`. See below for exact details.

**The whole solution (for me):**

I had to make the following changes to `rollup.config.js` as well as `package.json` to fix the problem:

1. I had to make 2 changes my `rollup.config.js`:

```
export default {
    client: {
        ...,
        plugins: [
            ...,
            resolve({
                ...
                preferBuiltins: false // ADD THIS
            }),
            commonjs({
              ...,
              namedExports: {
                "resource-loader": ["Resource"] // ADD THIS
              }
            })
        ],
        ...,
    },
    ...,
};
```

2. In `package.json`, I had to change `polka: 'next'` -> `polka: '^0.5.2` (latest version of polka).

Here is my final `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "TODO",
  "description": "TODO",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "polka": "^0.5.2", // THIS
    ...,
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got `window is not defined` at @pixi\polyfill\lib\polyfill.js

Answer (score 0):

Currently my solutions is using dynamic import inside `onMount`.

```js
<script>
  import {onMount} from 'svelte'

  onMount(async () => {
    const PIXI = await import('pixi.js')
    let type = "WebGL"
    if(!PIXI.utils.isWebGLSupported()){
      type = "canvas"
    }

    PIXI.utils.sayHello(type)
  })
</script>
```

"sapper": "^0.28.0" 
"svelte": "^3.17.3" 
"pixi.js": "^5.3.3"

Answer (score 0):

In your rollup.config  search for resolve

paste this there

```
resolve({
      preferBuiltins: false,
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    })
```